# SQL Server Management Studio: how to parse stored procedure code and check if table columns exist?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms, parse

I'm afraid that SSMS won't parse table columns within a stored procedure.

When you click in `Parse` option

[image]

SSMS says that parse is completed, even when a **procedure is selecting a column that does not exists in a table**.

When you run your script, SSMS shows what the `Parse` should warn about:

[image]

Is there a way to parse a script in order to check if table fields really exist before creating or altering procedures?

Comment: Column verification is "Binding" phase job and not "Parse" phase. (Query Execution = Parsing-->Binding-->Optimization-->Execution)

Comment: That is defined behavior, and it's by design. The "Parse" ***only*** check for syntactical errors. It does **NOT** check for object existence, and I'm not aware of any way or option to turn this on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's any way to do this with a parse, but you could try running the script inside a transaction then rolling back that transaction at the end. If there's an error, it should throw it, but even if there isn't, there won't be any lasting changes.

Answer (score 1):

Parse checks that the syntax of the query is correct, but it does not check the object names.

It can not check object name: if you are using nested SPs with temp tables for example, the temp table will not exist when the subsequent SP is parsed (it is defined in the 'parent' sp).